# How can I create a LINQ2SQL query that doesn't use MILLISECOND in the call to DATEDIFF?

Tags: linq-to-sql

By default if you compare two dates in a LINQ2SQL query, the resulting SQL will be

```
DATEDIFF(MILLISECOND, .....)
```

which requires using `BIGINT` as well and usually some `CONVERT` calls depending on what you're doing. As an example, try looking at the SQL output if you write

```
(DateTime1 - DateTime2).Days
```

It's a mess!

I would just like to call `DATEDIFF(DAY, ...)` for example. Is this possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is possible! It turns out there are a few nice methods located in `System.Data.Linq.SqlClient` that do exactly this.

```
DateDiffDay
DateDiffMinute
DateDiffMillisecond
.....
```

The resulting call to `DATEDIFF` will contain the appropriate first parameter and you can forget about all the calls to `CONVERT`.